# Namespacing in socket.io will not work

Tags: namespaces, socket.io

why this not work guys.

server

```
io.of('/chat').on('conection',function(socket){
socket.emit('id', {id : socket.id});
});
```

client

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080/chat');
socket.on('id', function(data){
   alert(data.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

because there's a typo --> conection vs connection?